# How can I run my own python service at a given time?

Tags: python, service

I have created a python service
(based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lmFArB6OI8&ab_channel=MATRIX)

and I noticed that after a while it stopped by itself

here is the code:

```
# these methods are working well
 def job(t):
     del()
     create()
     time.sleep(5)
     copy()
     time.sleep(2)
     cut()
     correct()


class aservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "SERVICE_NAME"
    _svc_display_name_ = "DISPLAY_NAME"
    _svc_description_ = "XYZ."


    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))

        # self.timeout = 640000    #640 seconds / 10 minutes (value is in milliseconds)
        self.timeout = 10000  # 120 seconds / 2 minutes
        # This is how long the service will wait to run / refresh itself (see script below)

        while 1:
            # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # Stop signal encountered
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("SomeShortNameVersion - STOPPED!")  # For Event Log
                break
            else:

                # Ok, here's the real money shot right here.
                # [actual service code between rests]
                try:
                   


 schedule.every().day.at("10:20").do(job,'It is 01:00')



 while True:
     schedule.run_pending()
     time.sleep(60)




                except:
                    pass
                # [actual service code between rests]


def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(aservice)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
        win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(aservice)
```

If I don't do it as a service, it works, as soon as I put it in a service it runs and stops after a while

I tried to simply run the methods in the task scheduler, I got a "0x1" error there, I tried to solve that too, but it didn't want to succeed.